# sys.stdout.write not working as expected in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, sys

I have two functions `prints()` and `clear()`. The function `prints()` print lines of text and the function `clear()` delete the printed lines with this method:

```
def clear():
    i = 0
    while True:
        if(i > globals['l']):
            break
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("\033[F \033[K")
            i += 1
```

where `globals['l']` is the number of lines to clear.

Then after the function `clear()` runs and the lines are cleared, the function `prints()` run again etc...

I don't understand why the function `clear()` is clearing only 22 lines of 32 lines.  But if I have, for example, 19 lines it is working perfectly. Where is the problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: As an aside, this could be a one-liner: says.stdout.write("\033[F \033[K" * l)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the problem is still there

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def clear(line_count):
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F \033[K" * line_count)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Works only on Unix systems

You can use:

```
print("\033c")
```

Or:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["printf", "\033c"])
```

Comment: it works only on Unix systems, I tried several alternatives for windows, but I haven't found the solution